# HttpGet Action does not get invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

Startup.cs, boiler plate:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I have one controller class, MembersController.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Members")]
public class MembersController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{email},{password}")]
    [Route("api/members/authenticate/")]
    public async void Authenticate(String email, String password)
    {
        ///the method that won't fire
    }


    // GET: api/Members/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetMember([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        ///the boiler plate method that gets called
    }
}
```

Basically I tried to add a method, `Authenticate`, where I take a `username` and `password`. I set a route and some HTTPGet arguments. But not matter how much I mess with it (traveling to `http://localhost:64880/api/members/authenticate/` , as an example), I cannot get my added Authenticate method to get called.

I imagine this is a routing thing?

Comment: How come you have a `void` returntype for Authenticate?

Comment: @Sigge I hadn't created my return types yet. Just installed Auth0 and wanted to start plugging into that. I don't think that should really matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing routes.

Given that you have the controller adorned with `[Route("api/Members")]` as a route prefix and then have the actions decorated with `[Route("api/members/authenticate/")]`, the resulting route for that action would be `api/Members/api/members/authenticate/`. See the difference to what you were trying to call?

Normally you would want to do a POST for the authenticate action so as to allow the parameters to be sent to the action in the body of the request.

Create a model to hold the data

```
public class AuthModel {
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

Next fix the routes. You appear to be using Attribute routing, was also mixing the route templates of the route attribute and http verb attributes.

*From comments*

> Also, that `[Produces("application/json")]` is completely pointless since JSON is the default

```
[Route("api/Members")]
public class MembersController : Controller {

    //Matches POST api/members/authenticate
    [HttpPost("authenticate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromBody] AuthModel model) {
        String email = model.email;
        String password = model.password

        //fake async task
        await Task.Delay(1);

        return Ok();
    }

    // GET: api/Members/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetMember([FromRoute] int id) {
        ///the boiler plate method that gets called

        //fake async task
        await Task.Delay(1);

        return Ok();
    }

}
```

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#attribute-routing)